# WP REST API Validate file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want users to be able to upload avatars. I need to validate the files sent by users in terms of file format and size.
I have written the following code, but I cannot get the avatar field in args.

```php
register_rest_route( self::NAMESPACE, '/user', [
    [
        'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
        'callback'            => [User::class, 'update'],
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        'args'                => [
            'avatar'           => [
                'description'       => __( 'User avatar' ),
                'required'          => false,
                'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                    // This method is not called
                    return true;
                },
            ],
        ],
    ],
] );
```

The file can be received in the update method of the user class, but I need to verify the file before sending it to this method.

```php
public static function update(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    return $request->get_file_params();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is not called because Uploads files aren't merged in, but can be accessed separately. What is happening is that the file is not merged into args so the validation callback will not affect it.

For you to know that the file is sent separately set required to "true" then you will get an error telling you about missing args

```
     register_rest_route( self::NAMESPACE, '/user', [
    [
        'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
        'callback'            => [User::class, 'update'],
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        'args'                => [
            'avatar'           => [
                'description'       => __( 'User avatar' ),
                'required'          => false,
                'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                    // The validation code will not run because
                    // Uploads aren't merged in but can be accessed separately.
                    return true;
                },
            ],
        ],
    ],
] );
```

If you need to validate the files args then you need to do it from the main callback function like so:

```
   public static function update(WP_REST_Request $request)
    {
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($request->get_file_params()['avatar']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $valid_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png");

       //This checks if the file is an image.
        if(!in_array(strtolower($imageFileType), $valid_extensions)) {
        $message =  'Invalid file type. You can only upload "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG" files';
            return new WP_Error('invalid_file_type', $message , ['status' => 400]);
        }
    }
```

check this link for reference https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: I know that this method will be called when it is sent as text or number, but when it is sent as a file this method will not work anymore.

Comment: You can only know if the method is being called by putting doing a proper validation. for e.g what do you want to check for can just return true for the validation to work.

Comment: Have you tried writing a proper validation code there and the method was not called? When you return true you are telling the code that the validation is valid.

Comment: Yes, even if I set `return false;`, nothing will be done. For debugging, I wanted to save the value of $param (`file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/debug.txt', json_encode($param));`) but this method is not called at all.

Comment: I have provided an update to the solution, I guess that fixes it for you